# PDF Rendering in Rapsbery Kiosk OS

Tags: pdf, raspberry-pi, chromium

I try to run a Kiosk System on a Raspberry Pi, Showing a Homepage with embedderd PDF-File.

I tried the systems [FullpageOS](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS) and [chilipie-kiosk](https://github.com/futurice/chilipie-kiosk). Both are using Chromium as Browser and the Displays Homepage uses the Build in PDF Viewer to display the PDF:

```
<object [data]="PdfURL" type="application/pdf" class="clientheight" width="100%">
    <embed [src]="PdfURL" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

The problem is, both distributions will render the PDFs wrong. They make several text elements float in each other like this:

[image: Error Sample Picture]

If I use Chromium on Windows or with the official "Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software" the PDF will be rendered as expected

[image: Sample image with no error]

I can't find any difference between the chromium at FullPageOS (witch I have builded based on the current version of Raspberry Pi OS) and the version of Raspberry Pi OS itself.

Maybe someone knows problems like this and can explain me, where it comes from and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first screenshot the text is rendered using Verdana while the second one uses Arial. It is possible that the font used for text is not embedded in the PDF file and each viewer uses its own default font (this is just a guess).
Please post a link to the PDF file to take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t post the PDF itself, because it belongs to a customer and I’m not allowed to publish his documents. That’s why I only posted tiny parts of the document.
But you are right, it is an issue of Fonts. I copied all Fonts from the /usr/share/fonts/ folder of the full Raspberry OS package to /home/pi/.fonts on FullpageOS. After doing this the PFDs become rendered well on FullpageOS, too. 
I will ask the customer to produce PDF files with embedded fonts. As Fallback I will find out how to add more fonts to my FullPage Image.
Thank you very much!